# ArcGIS Arcade return x coordinate of web map feature from EPSG: 3857 to EPSG: 2227

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-online, arcade

I'm using smart forms in ArcGIS Field Maps and I need to calculate the x coordinate in the feature layer's original coordinate system (California state plane III, EPSG:2227) when a new feature is added to the map.

The feature layer was originally in 2227 when published to AGOL but when I try to use the geometry function in Arcade it uses 3857 (web map coordinates).

```
Geometry($originalFeature)["x"]
```

returns:

```
number: -13610189.8467
```

Can I add a parameter like `"spatialReference": 2227` to get the expression to return values in state plane?

Comment: Have you looked on the [ESRI Community forum site](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcade-projectas-geometry-function/idi-p/1171382)?

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in a [comment by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/476436/arcgis-arcade-return-x-coordinate-of-web-map-feature-from-epsg-3857-to-epsg-22/477678#comment779395_476436) there has been an ArcGIS Pro Idea submitted for an [Arcade projectAs Geometry Function](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcade-projectas-geometry-function/idi-p/1171382) to be implemented.  In the words of  @JacobFougstrupNicolajsen who submitted it:

> Working primarily with data in UTM projection, I often need ways to
> convert UTM coordinates to WGS to create deep links to various online
> services.
>
> Having to create duplicate datasets, or running python scripts as
> regular intervals is tedious and time consuming.
>
> And [sic] arcade equivalent of the python projectAs method would solve
> almost all these issues.

The status of that enhencement request is currently Under Consideration.